# Nginx reverse proxy is returning 404

Tags: nginx

I've Googled this problem and found lots of information about it.  But for some reason no matter what I do it's not working for me.  The following is my site.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www3.mohave.gov;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server{

    listen       443 ssl http2; # default_server;
    server_name  www3.mohave.gov;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mohave_gov_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/mohave_gov_error.log debug;
    
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/mohave_gov_ssl.conf;
    # root /var/www/html;
    

    location /health {
        return 200 "healthy\n";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;       

        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;       
                
        proxy_pass https://www.mohave.gov:443/;
        # proxy_pass https://www.mohave.gov/;
        # proxy_pass https://www.mohave.gov;
        # proxy_pass https://internal_ip:443/;
        # proxy_pass https://internal_ip/;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;

    }   
}
```

I'm trying hit the default page of

https://www3.mohave.gov and event the default page https://www3.mohave.gov/Default.aspx
but no matter what I keep getting a 404.  My proxy_pass samples are from what I've been reading throughout Google.  I can ping the server [www.mohave.gov](http://www.mohave.gov) from nginx server and verified it with  the command:

```
telnet www.mohave.gov 443
```

which returns:

Trying 10.4.1.8...
Connected to [www.mohave.gov](http://www.mohave.gov).

Any ideas or tips that help me solve this?

**Update**

Ok I think the problem is that the server I'm trying to reach only uses 443 and part of my researched showed that I need to put the pem certificate in the reverse proxy.  I will try that and update

**Update**

When I reverse proxy to a site that accepts port 80 it works fine, but for SSL is the issue.  I followed the following steps:

I export the certificate from the pfx using the following command:

```
Exporting the certificate only:
# openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out mohave.gov.pem


location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;      

    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;       
            

    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mohave_gov/5_13_2022/mohave.gov.pem;
    proxy_ssl_verify  off;

    # proxy_pass https://www.mohave.gov:443/;
    proxy_pass https://www.mohave.gov/;
    # proxy_pass https://10.4.1.8:443/;
    # proxy_pass https://10.4.1.8/;
    # proxy_pass https://10.4.1.8;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;

}
```

but I'm still getting a 404 error.

Comment: Remove the `proxy_set_header Host $host;` line.

Comment: Your site appears to be working fine. Are you actually still having a problem?

Comment: It just did a reverse proxy to port 80 and not 443.  From what I read it seems you need to create a CA trusted cert from client to server, etc.

Comment: The certificate looks good to me but I get `500 Internal Server Error` can you show us the current config file and maybe any errors from the logs?